# Multi-window app calling method from different class

Tags: java, methods, jframe, window

I want to call the method named **test** which is in class StoreManager.
The class that I'm calling it from is named **Gui**

```
public class StoreManager extends JFrame
{
  JFrame jf = new JFrame(); 

  public void table() 
  { 
   JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JButton b; 
        jf.setSize(200, 100);
        jf.setTitle("test");
        jf.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setVisible(true);

        b = new JButton("button");
        b.setBounds(20, 20, 125, 25);

        p.add(b);
     }
```

And now in class **Gui** where I call the class I have

```
public class Gui
{
 private StoreManager sm = new StoreManager(); //calling instance of the class with test window
 //code to create its own window

 //some button to call this table
 sm.table(); //calling the method form StoreManager
```

When i Compile this table method from store manager I getting blank window.

Does any one has a idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `table()` method at all, build all you need in constructor and use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()` to use `JFrame` like so :

```
public class StoreManager extends JFrame
   {
   public StoreManager(){
     JFrame jf = new JFrame();
     JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JButton b; 
        jf.setSize(200, 100);
        jf.setTitle("test");
        jf.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setVisible(true);

        b = new JButton("button");
        b.setBounds(20, 20, 125, 25);

        p.add(b);
        jf.add(p);
       }

   }


public class Gui
{
public static void main(String[]args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            new StoreManager();
        }
    });
}   
}
```

And don't forget to add panel to jframe : `jf.add(p);` you are missing this in your code

Comment: p.add(jf); window appear but blank and error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: can some one help me with this ?